# Weird values when passing an array of structs as an openCL kernel argument

Tags: struct, kernel, opencl, arguments

When passing an array of structs to my kernel as an argument, I get weird values for the items after the first (array[1], array[2], etc).  It seems to be an alignment issue maybe?

Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct Sphere
{
    float3 color;
    float3 position;
    float3 reflectivity;
    float radius;
    int phong;
    bool isReflective;
} Sphere;
```

Here is the host side init code:

```
cl::Buffer cl_spheres = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(Sphere) * MAX_SPHERES, NULL, &err);
err = queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(cl_spheres, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(Sphere) * MAX_SPHERES, spheres, NULL, &event);
err = kernel.setArg(3, cl_spheres);
```

What happens is that the color for the second Sphere struct in the array will actually have the last value of what I set color to on the host side (s3 or z), a non initialized zero value, and the first value of what I set position to on the host side (s0 or x).  I noticed that the float3 datatype actually still has a fourth value (s3) that does not get initialized.  I think that is where the non initialized zero value is coming from.  So it seems that it is an alignment issue.  I really am at a loss as to what I could do to fix it.  I was hoping maybe someone could shed some light on this problem.  I have ensured that my struct definitions are exactly the same on both sides.

Comment: Can you show your clEnqueueWriteBuffer code?  I think there's a problem with the `bool` causing a misaligned padding.  Also consider using the `cl_[datatype]` types for host code when you're passing structures.

Comment: Done.  I am using the c++ bindings.  I use the cl_datatypes religiously.

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenCL 1.2 specs, section 6.11.1:

> Note that the alignment of any given struct or union type is required
>   by the ISO C standard to be at least a perfect multiple of the lowest
>   common multiple of the alignments of all of the members of the struct
>   or union in question and must also be a power of two.

Also `cl_float3` counts as a `cl_float4`, see section 6.1.5.

Finally, in section 6.9.k:

> Arguments to kernel functions in a program cannot be declared with the
>   built-in scalar types bool, half, size_t, ptrdiff_t, intptr_t, and
>   uintptr_t or a struct and/or union that contain fields declared to be
>   one of these built-in scalar types.

To comply with these rules, and probably make accesses faster, you can try (OpenCL C side; on the host use `cl_float4`):

```
typedef struct Sphere
{
    float4 color;
    float4 position;
    float4 reflectivity;
    float4 radiusPhongReflective; // each value uses 1 float
} Sphere;
```